# how to get multiple columns(mysql_fetch_assoc()) values in smarty

Tags: mysql, smarty

i have a simple problem but i have just started smarty so bit problem
here is my code

```
     $value=array();
     $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fawadtest");
     while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $value[] = $row;
}
       $smarty->assign('array',$value);
```

here is my tpl file

```
   <table border="2">
   <tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th>Name></th><th>Username</th><th>Password</th>           <th>Email</th></tr>
  {section name=index loop=$array}

    <tr>
        <td>{$array[index].name}</td>
        <td>{$array[index].username}</td>
        <td>{$array[index].password}</td>
        <td>{$array[index].email}</td>
    <tr>
 {/section}
```

i want to retrive all columns i-e (name,username,password,email from table fawadtest ) from a query and show it in a table

Answer (score 1):

Try the foreach function of smarty

```
{foreach from=$array item=row}
    {$row.name} - {$row.username} - ...
{foreachelse}
    No data found
{/foreach}
```